# How to concatenate all the rows linked with a same id into one row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to write a script for a table to concatenate the entries linked with the particular id.That is how an output should look like.

[image: my code]

```
"IF DSW2011_gUDT.sOpState = 1 OR DSW2012_gUDT.sOpState =1 OR DSW2013_gUDT.sOpState =1 OR DSW2014_gUDT.sOpState =1 OR DSW2015_gUDT.sOpState =1 OR DSW2021_gUDT.sOpState =1 OR DSW2022_gUDT.sOpState =1".
```

[image: table shows one id linked with several entries]

Comment: add your table structure in question

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id and merge them by grouping..
in short ,Group them.